# How to find a bug in my date arithmetic shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I wrote below piece of code to calculate the date after a given date:

```
date=$DATE_FINAL
declare -a  max_month=(0 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31)
eval $(echo $date|sed 's!\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)!year=\1;month=\2;day=\3!')
(( year4=year%4 ))
(( year100=year%100 ))
(( year400=year%400 ))
if [ \( $year4 -eq 0 -a \
        $year100 -ne 0 \) -o \
     $year400 -eq 0 ]
then
declare -a  max_month=(0 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31)
fi
day=$((day+1))
if [ $day -gt ${max_month[$month]} ] >| /wload/baot/home/baoted9/logs_bde27_conversion_1/ataa_display.logs 2>&1
then
  day=1
  month=$((month+1))
  if [ $month -gt 12 ]
  then
    year=$((year+1))
    month=1
  fi
fi
if [ $month -eq "08" ] ||  [ $month -eq "09" ]
then
future_date_final=$(echo $year"$month"$day)
else
future_date_final=$(printf "%4.4d%2.2d%2.2d" $year $month $day)
fi
echo "this is your final business date $future_date_final"
```

It calculates the date correctly however throws an error at the end of the code as below -

```
line 79: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

It just looks too ugly, not sure how to remove it as otherwise code is working fine, tried redirecting it to a log file still appearing.
Also, I am facing issue with below code for a plain cd command with code highlighted in red -

```
echo "pset  date $Param_date_1"
cd /wload/baot/home/baotasa0/sandboxes_finance/ext_ukba_bde/pset >| /wload/baot/home/baoted9/logs_bde27_conversion_1/at_display.logs 2>&1
sh UKBA_publish.sh UKBA $Param_date_1 3 >| /wload/baot/home/baoted9/logs_bde27_conversion_1/ate_display.logs 2>&1
```

Error is -

```
./auto2.sh: line 190: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Hmmm, may I suggest https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49053/linux-add-x-days-to-date-and-get-new-virtual-date ?

Comment: The error on line 79 *does* impact correctness -- it'll make your comparison always false, whether it *should* be true or false.

Comment: ...that issue is because numbers starting with a leading 0 are parsed as octal, and `8` is of course an impossible digit in octal numbers. Don't put leading zeros on your values used for calculation -- add them in at output time only.

Comment: Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it finds. And [stop using `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: (BTW -- StackOverflow is a Q&A database, not a forum. That's critical, because it's why we insist on having quality questions as well as quality answers: Both are written not just to help the person with a problem, but to help *everyone with a similar problem* in the future; thus, we care more about future readers, of which there are many, than the person who first came in with a question, of which there is only one -- hence all the rules lawyering, of which you're likely to see much).

Comment: You might be better off with a conversion to and from a julian day number.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that if you're using `$((val+1))` where `$val` is beginning with a `0`, then `bash` isn't operating on decimal base but on octal base. Since `08` isn't a valid number in octal base, it complains.

You can force decimal representation by writing

```
$((10#$val+1))
```

Please note, that by doing so, any preceding zeros are removed. If you need to have a representation with preceding zero, just use

```
val=$(printf '%02d' $((10#$val+1)))
```

For reference, see the `bash` [manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers. A leading ‘0x’ or ‘0X’ denotes hexadecimal. Otherwise, numbers take the form [base#]n, where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base. If base# is omitted, then base 10 is used. When specifying n, the digits greater than 9 are represented by the lowercase letters, the uppercase letters, ‘@’, and ‘_’, in that order. If base is less than or equal to 36, lowercase and uppercase letters may be used interchangeably to represent numbers between 10 and 35.

---

*P.S.: This is a very good article about [falsehoods programmers believe about time](http://FalsehoodsAboutTime.com) I had to read myself. If possible, try to use `date -d` instead of doing manual date arithmetic. You can use for instance `date -d "+5 days" +%d.%m.%Y` to get the date in five days.*